# React progress element has a bug on IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

Why is IE10 (I haven't checked in IE11 and above) rendering value 1, regardless of the value I am passing in, when rendering a progress element using React?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Check out this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/co4wz3ft/5/

It works as expected in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: IE 10 should support progress. Maybe, it is ignoring the max attribute. If max attribute is ignored, value should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Vijay - have you looked at the fiddle? The plain HTML progress renders just fine. Only the React version has an issue. It could be the max attribute being ignored. But why?

Comment: I checked the fiddle in Chrome. I don't have IE. Is React rendering the same way in IE or using some sort of polyfill?

Comment: can confirm that this also exists in IE11. My suspicion is that the React is doing some funky things to the value attribute

Comment: Seems to works in React v0.14.8 so it could be related to a change in v15.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After countless desperate attempts, I found out that inverting the order of the properties (declaring `max` before `value`) fixes the issue:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <progress max="100" value="50"></progress>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I assume React was trying to set the value, before setting max, then value would be trimmed to the default max, which is one. But I am still keen to hear a better explanation from someone else!

Comment: You, sir, deserve three beers. And this should be marked as the solution.

Comment: Another one from me. So stupid bug! :) It's not only IE10 related, my Windows 10 UWP app that is rendered using Edge engine reproduces it as well.

Comment: This seems to be the proper answer.  The other solution just takes advantage of the fact that if max is not specified then it assumes it is 1.  If we specify max first, we can use it as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Hello I've updated your fiddle like this and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/co4wz3ft/11/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <progress value="0.7"></progress>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

It needs further investigation but you may use it like that right now.

[image]

Comment: confirmed that it works on IE10 in a VM, 
does wrapping it in a div prevent it from turning into a react component?

Comment: @derp It is already a React component wrapped or not wrapped in with div. You may aswell return just the `<progress />` element which would be better. I will update code in the answer :)